# How to unpack dictionary values inside a beam.Map with Python Apache Beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have this function used inside a beam.Map :

```
def to_row(self, record):
    tags = {
        "foo": "bar"
    }

    x = {**tags}

    return beam.Row(
        date=record.get("date"),
        value=record.get("input_value").get("value"),
    )
```

When the function is runned in a pipeline, because of the statement x={**tags}, it breaks and give this error :

```
 TypeError: Attempted to determine schema for unsupported type 'Any'
```

If i remove the x=... statement, everything works.

I understand that Apache Beam is typed even in python, but I dont really understand why I cant unpack values.

Is there a way to unpack properly without this problem? Ideally I would like pass a Dict[str,str] into the beam.Row without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `x` and `tags` used in your code?

If you want to pass a `Dict[str, str]` to `beam.Row`, just unpack it:`beam.Row(**tags)`.

In your code, `x` is still a `Dict[str, str]` that equals to `tags`.

Comment: `x` and `tags` are not used anywhere outside of the function. x was added just for the sake of the question.

`beam.Row(**tags))`  does not work either , it gives the same error. In other word my problem is that I cant unpack anything and I dont understand why Apache Beam prevent me to do that.

Comment: `x` and `tags` shouldn't affect the pipeline execution since they are not used. The type error should be raised [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/typehints/schemas.py#L295). So it means that your element_type missed this [line](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/typehints/schemas.py#L288). You can check the element_type of a PCollection by `pcollection.element_type`. Can you also try defining the lambda inline or use NamedTuple like `pc = input | beam.Map(lambda ...).with_output_types(NamedTupleSchema)`?

Comment: Ah I see, You were right , my mistake was not in the unpacking but with the fact that 

I was using `apache_beam.dataframe.convert.to_dataframe` after. Providing a proxy to the function `to_dataframe`  fixed my problem

Comment: @BigJerBD could you elaborate on what fixed your issue? I'm facing the exact same thing - trying to convert a dict to a row (currently using beam.Row(**my_dict) ), and then converting that to_dataframe, hitting the error you got. What do you mean you provided a proxy?

Comment: yes i have the same problem, would be great to have a more elaborated solution please